# Validating single object in the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have a view model in which I have series of models since I need to display and get multiple models in the same page. For example

```
class ViewModel {
     public RegisteratioModel Rm {get; set;}
     public LoginModel LM{get; set;}
}
```

in each one these model I've used data annotations for validation, for example

```
public RegistrationModel {
   [Required]
   public String Username {get; set;}
}
```

When I try to validate a single object in my ViewModel using

```
tryValidate(viewModel.Rm)
if (ModelState.isValid) {}
```

The `ModelState` is always invalid and I think it is because other objects are undergoing validation too. How can I validate a single object in my model only?

Comment: What is the purpose for embedding the models? If you aren't validating all of them (except one), then they are for display purposes? Remember, the model of in View-Model-Controller is a view model, not a data model. So you would have a view model defined for a single view, which would contain all of the data required for the view to render and behave as intended. So you shouldn't have embedded other view models being displayed by a single view.

Comment: @KeithPayne: What if I need to multiple models in my view, I can make partial views but that's a lot of work! sometimes I need a model and a  list of models. View.Bag in my openion is not good way to do it

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly validating a single property, behind the scenes it will validate all your properties, but, it is returning the one that you specify by the properties name, and if there are issues with any other properties, they wont be added to the modelstate.

```
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, model.GetType());

string propertyName = "";

ModelValidationResult result = ModelValidator.GetModelValidator(metadata, ControllerContext)
                                             .Validate(null)
                                             .First(m => m.MemberName == propertyName);
```

Also... this will only work within your controllers...